# Select multiple weeks via week input

Tags: javascript, html, input, jquery-week-calendar

I have a week input

```
 <input type="week" name="weeks" id="weeks">
```

I want to be able to select multiple weeks with this input. I tried the "multiple" parameter but it didn't work. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this idea:

In your JS:

```
 var weeks = [] //here store the weeks selected by the user; 
 function handler(e){
    weeks.push(e.target.value)
 }
```

In your HTML:

```
 <input type="week" name="week" id="weeks" onchange="handler(event);">

 <div class='weeks'>
         <-- here you can display the selected weeks --!>
 </div>
```

Show to the user only one input, and when he selects a week you save this week in the weeks array, and clear the week input to allow him to select another week.

Comment: Please tell how to "Show to the user only one input, and when he selects a week you save this week in the weeks array, and clear the week input to allow him to select another week.".

Comment: Good idea but i want the user to see the selected week. Clearing the input doesn't work for me.

Comment: I edit the response, you can chek if it's ok

Comment: Hi @zokani you can show the content of the array weeks to the user :) .